# Deploying Meteor on a CDN or S3

Tags: deployment, amazon-s3, meteor, cdn, frontend

Is there a way to get the static assets generated by a Meteor app deployed on a **CDN** - or a static hosting solution like **S3** - in order to improve loading speed and reduce hosting costs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If deploying through [demeteorizer](https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer), it is pretty easy to upload the content of the `static_cacheable` to a CDN and change the links in `app.html` and `app.json`.

That process can probably be automated in a custom deploy/capistrano script.

Comment: I'll accept other answers if someone comes up with something more simple/built-in.

Answer (score 1):

### CloudFront

I've detailed how we accomplished this at Edthena in [this post](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/cdn). The TLDR is:

Add this line somewhere in your server code:

```
WebAppInternals.setBundledJsCssPrefix(CDN_URL);
```

Where `CDN_URL` is your CloudFront URL (e.g. https://a27n0s89ik4xb3.cloudfront.net).

We kept the defaults when creating the CloudFront distribution except for the following:

```
Origin Domain Name: myapp.example.com
Origin ID: myapp.example.com
Viewer Protocol Policy: HTTPS Only
Compress Objects Automatically: yes
```

If you serve your own fonts, you can end up with cross origin errors (unless you use a font data URL). Josh Owens describes how to deal with that in [his post](http://joshowens.me/using-a-cdn-with-your-production-meteor-app/).

### CloudFlare

Have a look at [Cloudflare Meets Meteor](https://meteorhacks.com/cloudflare-meets-meteor/) on the meteorhacks blog. If you happen to be a CloudFlare user, it's a pretty easy solution but you'll need to disable WebSockets (or pay a lot, or use a complex workaround).

Comment: Cloudflare works great if the websocket is set to a different server using `DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL`. There's a good example here: https://github.com/rclai/meteor-app-with-remote-server

Answer (score 0):

If you are using meteorite, you can use this package: https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-aws-sdk

Comment: This is to access your S3 buckets. I'm after having meteor link to/upload its static assets remotely there.